# SQL SubQuery for "Create a report that shows the product name and supplier id for all products supplied by Exotic Liquids, and Tokyo Traders"

Tags: sql

Create a report that shows the product name and supplier id for all products supplied by Exotic Liquids, and Tokyo Traders. (Tables : Products & Suppliers)
This is from Famous Northwind DB....
Kindly tell the query.. I am stuck on it.

Comment: please enter sample data and desired output. Normally, the desired information can be easily obtained with a join between two tables

Answer (score 0):

There's a convenient ER diagram of the Northwind datbase [here](https://documentation.red-gate.com/dms6/data-masker-help/sample-masking-sets-and-databases/an-er-diagram-for-the-northwind-sample-database).

So you have two supplier names 'Exotic Liquids' and 'Tokyo Traders'.  Suppliers are in the `SUPPLIERS` table and their names are in the `.companyname` column.

To get one supplier is easy:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   SUPPLIERS 
WHERE  companyname = 'Exotic Liquids';
```

To get both you can either use an OR clause or an IN(..) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   SUPPLIERS 
WHERE  companyname IN('Exotic Liquids','Tokyo Traders');
```

Now product names are in the `.productname` column of the `PRODUCTS` table.  The PRODUCTS table is related to the SUPPLIERS table through the `PRODUCTS.supplierid` column which points to the `SUPPLIERS.supplierid` column.

If you already knew the supplier id's for the products that you were interested in you could get their product names like this:

```
SELECT productname 
FROM   PRODUCTS 
WHERE  supplierid IN(1001,1002);
```

where 1001 and 1002 are the supplier ids of Exotic Liquids and Tokyo Traders.
However, because we do not know them ahead of time (we just know their company names) we need to combine these two queries like so:

```
SELECT p.productname, p.supplierid
FROM   PRODUCTS p
WHERE  p.supplierid IN( SELECT s.supplierid
                        FROM   SUPPLIERS s  
                        WHERE  s.companyname IN('Exotic Liquids','Tokyo Traders')
                       );
```

Which should do what you want.